# How to send binary data using gorequest

Tags: go

I am trying to send content of html file via **gorequest** PUT method. In documentation of service which I am trying to contact it is mentioned that type of body should be `Content-Type: application/octet-stream.`

When I execute:

```
req.Send(string(content))
```

where content is slice of bytes (`[]byte`), my html file is broken, because content of the file is encoded, and all white spaces, special characters like <, > are replaced.
When I execute:

```
req.Send(content)
```

I see that following content is sent: `[60,104,116,109, .... ]` which is not what I would expect. Can you advise me how to transfer html file as a byte stream to webservice using gorequest?

Comment: What is `gorequest`?

Comment: https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest

Comment: From the [gorequest docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest#SuperAgent.Send): "Send function accepts either json string or query strings ...".

Answer (score 0):

Either set `req.BounceToRawString` to `true` or change the content type to `text/plain` before sending the string.

From the docs at [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest):

> If you have set Type to text or Content-Type to text/plain, content will be sent as raw string in body instead of form